# How to prevent data in angular 4 on page refresh

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

We are using @ngrx/store for shopping cart to add items in cart and a service to store data (e.g. user id, order number etc.) but once the page is refreshed,the data from the store and the service is lost.

So please suggest us how we can prevent this data loss.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions to your issues:

1. Storing in Local storage (easiest and safest),
2. Store in url,
3. Sending to database before redirect, and fetch it after redirect.

There is no other way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your data somewhere if you want to keep them.

For that, you have several solutions :

- Local Storage / Session Storage : use this solution if you want to save the cart one the user's computer. This means it is not related to the account, so if he logs on another machine, the basket is lost.
- Database : This binds the shopping cart to the account. If he logs on another machine, then the cart is loaded .